# Need to import 2M of JSON into ONE Couchbase Document

Tags: couchbase

I've been given an odd requirement to store an Excel spreadsheet in one JSON document within Couchbase. `cbimport` is saying that my document is not valid JSON, when it is, so I believe something else is wrong.

My document goes along the style of this:

```
[{ "sets": [
   {
      "cluster" : "M1M",
      "type" : "SET",
      "shortName" : "MARTIN MARIETTA MATERIALS",
      "clusterName" : "MARTIN MARIETTA",
      "setNum" : "10000163"
   },
   {
      "shortName" : "STERLING INC",
      "type" : "SET",
      "cluster" : "SJW",
      "setNum" : "10001427",
      "clusterName" : "STERLING JEWELERS"
   },
   ...
]}]
```

And my cbimport command looks like this:

```
cbimport json --cluster localhost --bucket documentBucket \
--dataset file://set_numbers.json --username Administrator \
--password password --format lines -e errors.log -l debug.log \
--generate-key 1
```

I've tried to format as `lines` as well as `list`. Both fail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you expecting it to be imported into a single document? Or are you expecting one document for every item in the "sets" array?

Comment: A single document. That's what makes the requirement so odd.

Comment: I just tried it locally (with `list`) and it imported successfully into a single document: `cbimport json --cluster localhost --bucket documentBucket --dataset file://set_numbers.json --username Administrator --password password --format list --generate-key 1` - what version of Server are you using?

Comment: Version: 4.6.1-3652 Enterprise Edition (build-3652). The JSON file is almost 2M. Is that too big??

Comment: I was trying it with 5.5, so I'll try 4.6.1 and see what happens. 2MB should not be too large.

Comment: I'm sorry! I just noticed you said `list` instead of `lines`. It works for me too. Please answer my question so I can give you credit.

Comment: Your question states you tried lines and list. Typo?

Comment: No, I did try them both, but I tinkered a little with the JSON as well. So I actually had two problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote your sample to a json file called set_numbers.json and tried it locally with list.

> cbimport json --cluster localhost --bucket documentBucket --dataset
>   file://set_numbers.json --username Administrator --password password
>   --format list --generate-key 1

It imported successfully into a single document.

Answer (score 1):

use cbimport to upload json data

```
cbimport json -c couchbase://127.0.0.1 -b data -d file://data.json -u Administrator -p password -f list -g "%id%" -t 4
```